# Autofill HTML variable with hard brackets through URL

Tags: html

I have a script that I want to run on an HTML document and it recognizes the field to act on by passing an auto fill placeholder in the URL that I pass the script when I run it via the command prompt (Windows). So for example if I wanted the script to work on an element in the page with the name fieldname I would pass it this as its URL argument:

http://www.example.com/login.html?fieldname=placeholder

where fieldname is the name of the field in the HTML source that I want it to use, and it uses the same syntax as auto filling through a URL would.

My problem is that the page I want to run it on has the following for the element I want to fill out:

```
<input class="input-xlarge" id="user_login" name="user[login]" maxlength="128" type="text">
```

and if I pass http://www.example.com/login.html?user[login]=placeholder to my browser the field doesn't get auto filled and thus the script won't recognize it. I've also tried using user, login, and userlogin for the name with no success.

So my question is how do I auto fill forms that use hard brackets in their name field through the URL that would be passed to my browser?

Answer (score 0):

Pass this link, which as been encoded `encodeURI()`.

`http://www.example.com/login.html?user%5Blogin%5D=placeholder`

Then when you get the link on the recieving page, use `decodeURI()` to convert back to "[" and "]".

It should look like:

```
var url = decodeURI('http://www.example.com/login.html?user%5Blogin%5D=placeholder');
```

var `url` will contain the original URL.

## why? W3C quotation:

> "...Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters
>   "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters
>   used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL."

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by pass the URL as a variable like that from a command prompt. I guess I forgot to say this, but I'm running the script from the windows command prompt so I can't define a variable like that and decodeURI is not a known command which may be where the confusion came from.